# Can I use an if statement to check if a number is within a range?

Tags: python, if-statement, range, conditional-statements

I've started programming and I can't seem to answer a question.  I want to make an if statement on a variable number.

Can I use range(0,15) in an if statement to see if the number is within range?

If so, how?  Can't seem to find any info on this specific topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can! Best way is to try by yourself :)

```
if 3 in range(5):
    print('ok')
else:
    print('no')
```

Returns `ok`

Answer (score 7):

You don't need range, use an upper and lower bound:

```
number = 14
if 0  <= number < 15:
   # number is between 0 and 15
```

Comment: For simple bounds testing I agree this is the best approach; I'd only use the range/xrange technique if I wanted to test in an extended range.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following example.

```
number = 14

if number in range(0,15):
    print "Yes"
```

Comment: Note that this also works with extended ranges: eg `45 in range(40, 60, 5)`. In Python 2 use `xrange()` instead of `range()` or you'll be wastefully creating a list just to do the test.